# How do I successfully make a shell in c that when its followed by a text file containing commands, it parses the file and executes the commands?

Tags: c, file, shell, parsing, command-line-arguments

There are two modes to my shell: Interactive mode and File Mode. Interactive mode works fine and consists of a basic shell operations. The File Mode is the part I am having difficulty figuring out. To start the File mode you have to type in the name of the shell and directly after it a text file that has commands in it ex) ./myShell commands.txt
When I run it, it prints out the commands that are in the text file but it doesn't execute the commands and it says "ls: : No such file or directory". I was wondering if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank You!
The text file I am testing contains these 2 commands in this format:
ls -l

```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  void parse(char *input, char **vparas)
  {

   while(*input != '\0')
   {
     while(*input == ' ' || *input == '\t' || *input == '\n')
        *input++ = '\0';
     *vparas++ = input;
     while(*input != '\0' && *input != ' ' && *input != '\t' && *input != '\n')
     {
       input++;
     }
   }
  *vparas = '\0';
  }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int x;
 //file stuff///////////////////////////////////////////////////
 if(argc!= 2)
 printf("");
 else
  {
     FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     if(file == 0)
      {
       printf("Could not open file\n");
      }
      else
      {
      //get string and set it equal to some array

        char fileInput[1024];

        fgets(fileInput, 1024, file);
        printf("%s", fileInput);
        char *vparas[20];
        parse(fileInput, vparas);

        //execute file commands
        pid_t pid1;
        pid1 = fork();
        if(pid1<0)
        {
          printf("Fork Failed");
          return 1;
        }
        else if(pid1 == 0)
          execvp(*vparas,vparas);
        else
          wait(NULL);
       fclose(file);
        }
     }
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    char input[1024];
    char *args[64];
    while(1)
    {
      printf("@");
      gets(input);

      printf("\n");

     //parse the line
     parse(input, args);
     if(strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0)
       return 0;
     //execute command

     pid_t pid;
     pid = fork();
     if(pid<0)
     {
       printf("Fork Failed");
       return 1;
     }
     else if(pid== 0)
     {
       execvp(*args, args);

     }
     else
     {
       wait(NULL);
     }
   }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the script file yielding that error. And, please, format your code before posting.

Comment: The script file that was giving me the error had the commands:ls -l and nothing else. I hope that helps.

Comment: your current program reads only one command from file and executes right? you have not written loop to parse through file yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using fgets() to read from file the string read will contain last extra character( mostly newline character). So you need to change that to '\0' character then the execution of command input from file will be parsed properly. add this line after fgets().

```
fileInput[strlen(fileInput)-1]='\0';
```

it will execute single command from file. for multiple commands you can read from file inside a loop.

```
while(fgets(fileInput, 1024, file))
{
//rest of the code
}
```

Comment: accept answer which solves your problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/about) read this link.